# jQuery Prevent parent's event to be triggered when child's event is triggered

Tags: jquery, element, parent

Recently I have some problems with jQuery. Let's just say I have elements like this:

```
<div id="parent1" class="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="children">
        <a href="" id="child_link1" class="child_link"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have jQuery function like this:

```
$(".parent").click(function(){
    alert("parent is clicked");
});

$(".child_link").click(function(){
    alert("child link is clicked");
});
```

If I click the child_link, parent will be triggered too. How can I create a situation where if I click the child_link, parent won't be triggered?

Answer (score 9):

You need to stop propagation on the child click event, like this:

```
$(".child_link").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("child link is clicked");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2UB/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using the stopPropagation but unfortunately, even the child_link event was not triggered. It only went back to the top page doing nothing.

Comment: Did you remember to pass the event in to the function? `.click(function(e) {` <-- there

Answer (score 4):

Event handler for the child should be written like so:

```
$(".child_link").click(function( event ){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("child link is clicked");
});
```

This will stop [event bubbling](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), and parent's event handler will not get called.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using the stopPropagation but unfortunately, even the child_link event was not triggered. It only went back to the top page doing nothing.

Answer (score 4):

See your event is getting bubbling up to its parent. So here you have to use `.stopPropagation();`:

```
$(".child_link").click(function(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation(); //<----------------this stops the event to bubble up
  alert("child link is clicked");
});
```

Comment: reason for downvote? plz share.

Comment: I don't know who is down voting. I've up-voted you to compensate :)

Comment: @Jai Perhaps the reason of downvoting in doubling answers? What is in your answer new comparing with Rory McCrossan's one? The same absolutely applies to you Jan Hančič

Comment: there are some more comments in the answers to indicate the solution.

Comment: "So here you have to use .stopPropagation();" yes, very handy point, without this comment  author of question wouldn't came up to this conclusion.

Comment: That's not a reason to down-vote. Read the FAQ. And besides, Rory and I posted simultaneously.

Comment: It looks incriminating that my answer is the only one not downvoted, but it wasn't me. As said, duplicate answers within seconds can happen and is no reason to downvote. Have +1 from me guys.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried using the stopPropagation but unfortunately, even the child_link event was not triggered. It only went back to the top page doing nothing.